# MAC app : Unable to import Mac Distribution Profile in Organization

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, mac-app-store

MAC app submission,

I am getting issue while installing MAC app distribution profile. I got following steps from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3141323 , but still unable to install it. Getting errors as follow :

**Mac Provisioning Profile Details**

```
    Install your Mac Provisioning Profile on your system by:
        Double-clicking on the file in Finder
        Dragging the file to the Profiles Preference pane
        Clicking the + button in the Profiles Preference pane
```

For Distribution Profile, I am getting **error**

`Only Development Provisioning Profiles can be installed in System Preferences. Production Provisioning Profiles are imported within Xcode.`

---

```
    Add your Mac Provisioning Profile to the Xcode Organizer
        Dragging the file into the Xcode Organizer window
        Clicking the Import button in the Xcode Organizer window
```

Here, nothing is happending, profile is not getting installed, no error or anything.

---

**Studied links :** http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/10/submitting-your-first-mac-app-store-app/

Please provide some steps to install profile. Also if more detailed **document to submit mac app on mac appstore.**

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and I can't find my Distribution Provisioning Profiles from **Preferences > Accounts**. But when I create a Development Provisioning Profile for testing, I found all of Distribution Provisioning Profiles appear in account detail. And I can sign my Mac app then.

I guess there maybe bug when Xcode retrieve Mac Provisioning Profiles when there is only Distribution Provisioning Profile. And create a Development Provisioning Profile fix the problem.

[image: Account Details]

[image: Mac Provisioning Profiles (Development)]

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 13, a provisioning profile can be installed by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item.